# Android actionbar only show overflow

Tags: android, android-actionbar

my actionbar is only showing the items in overflow. the androidstudio displays the items correct in the actionbar (not overflow). if i run the app on emulator or on my device the items always appears in overflow

action_bar.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">



    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"

        app:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:title="home"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:title="share"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
```

themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyAppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyAppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

thanks for any help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Theme.Holo`. This means that you are trying to use the native action bar. In that case, change `app:showAsAction` to `android:showAsAction`.

Comment: sorry, this does not work. i changed the xmln:app to xmln:android and changed the app:showAsAction to android:showAsAction but then the error "menu item should specify a title" appears

Comment: @markus: "i changed the xmln:app to xmln:android" -- you will notice that I did not tell you to do that. That is because you already had an `xmlns:android` declaration, otherwise the rest of your XML would not work. Delete the `xmlns` declaration that you modified, leaving you with just a `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` declaration in the `<menu>` element. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ActionBar/ActionBarDemoNative/res/menu/actions.xml for an example menu resource.

Comment: thx CommonsWare for your help but if i delete the xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" i'm not able to specify showAsAction....

Comment: @markus: As I wrote in my answer, change `app:showAsAction` to `android:showAsAction`. Anywhere else in the file that you have `app:` as a namespace prefix on an XML attribute, change it to `android:`. At that point, if you wish, you can get rid of the `xmlns:app` declaration if you choose. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ActionBar/ActionBarDemoNative/res/menu/actions.xml for an example menu resource.

Comment: @CommonWare, thx again but i did ALL you have mentioned in your previous post. i've copied now all from your link but i get the following error on android:showAsAction "should use app:showAsAction with the appcompat library with xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto""

Comment: @markus: That is a separate problem. It should be a warning, not an error. To get rid of the warning, get rid of `appcompat-v7` from your project. If you are using Android Studio, and this is a simple Android Studio project, look in the `build.gradle` file in your `app` module, for a line in a `dependencies` closure that references `appcompat-v7`, and delete that line.

Comment: grrrr. THX A LOT!!! sorry about my stupidity. i was thinking i'm not able to combile the project whith that red line....

Comment: @markus: Getting rid of `appcompat-v7` is a pain. Glad to hear it is working for you now.

Answer (score 0):

The following code would solve your problem.

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_share"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
android:showAsAction="always"
android:title="share"/>
```

Note the `namespace` used for the attributes.